# Django GenericRelation not working

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-contenttypes

I have the following model in my app, using the content-type django framework :

```
class GenericMedia(models.Model):
    limit           = models.Q(model = 'Image') | models.Q(model = 'Video') | models.Q(model = 'Other')
    content_type    = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, limit_choices_to = limit)
    object_id       = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object  = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s" % os.path.basename(self.content_object.url.name)

    def instance(self):
        return self.content_object.__class__.__name__


class Media(models.Model):
    description     = models.CharField(blank = True, max_length = 500)
    link            = models.URLField(blank = True)
    genericFK       = generic.GenericRelation(GenericMedia, content_type_field='content_type', object_id_field='object_id')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s" % os.path.basename(self.url.name)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Media, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        generic_link = GenericMedia(content_object = self)
        generic_link.save()


class Image(Media):
    imgW = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    imgH = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    url  = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'mediamanager', height_field = 'imgH', width_field = 'imgW')
```

Everythings works fine, excepts the GenericRelation in my abstract Media Class.
In django documentation it is said that :

> If you delete an object that has a GenericRelation, any objects which
>   have a GenericForeignKey pointing at it will be deleted as well.

But my problem is that when I delete an image, the GenericMedia pointing to it is not deleted.

If anyone has a solution, thanks !

Comment: Please add what specific version of Django you are using, and a link to the documentation that says that about deletions.  I suspect this is an issue where the version number of the documentation and your code differs, because I don't remember seeing that line in the docs myself (though I could just be mistaken).

Comment: I'm using v 1.6.1 and the link to [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#reverse-generic-relations)

Comment: Okay, I guess it's not a version issue after all.  Another question, though -- when you say in your question "when I delete an image", you mean the Media object, not the Image object, right?

Comment: Yes, I delete the Media object through the django admin interface. But Media is just an abstract class, and image extends it (Media is not present in DB)

Comment: Oh, I see...  I can't see anything you're obviously doing wrong, then.  This could easily turn out to be a genuine bug in generic relations that are inherited from an abstract class.

Comment: Ok, thanks @AndrewGorcester. I will submit a ticket to support and post the answer as fast as I know the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned it, the documentation is clear about what happens when you delete an object that has a Generic Relation field (Django deletes all objects that have a foreign key to the object with GenericRelation).

So this is basically Django's fault (probably some problem with the abstract classes), BUT there is a way to overcome this situation.

By using `pre_delete` you can delete all objects that have a foreign key to the object with GenericRelation.

Some examples of `pre_delete` signal can be found here: http://www.koopman.me/2015/01/django-signals-example/